# How to add permalinks to contact form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I´m wondering if I can get the Post ID or permalink to be send as part of subject o message content of contact form7, any Idea?

Comment: This may be useful http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-iis-pretty-permalinks-with-404-redirect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047823/wordpress-contact-form-7-returns-404-but-works-on-homepage

Comment: @ManigandanArjunan: And how is this helpful? Both links you provided has nothing to do with question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact Form 7 has some special mail tags (http://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/)
You can insert them into the Message Body field or other fields in the Mail section.

- `[_remote_ip]` - This tag will be replaced by the sender’s client IP address.
- `[_user_agent]` - This tag will be replaced by the sender’s user agent information.
- `[_url]` - This tag will be replaced by the URL of the contact form.
- `[_date]` - This tag will be replaced by the date of the submission.
- `[_time]` - This tag will be replaced by the time of the submission.
- `[_post_id]` - This tag will be replaced by the ID of the post which contains the contact form.
- `[_post_name]` - This tag will be replaced by the name (slug) of the post which contains the contact form.
- `[_post_title]` - This tag will be replaced by the title of the post which contains the contact form.
- `[_post_url]` - This tag will be replaced by the permalink of the post which contains the contact form.
- `[_post_author]` - This tag will be replaced by the author name of the post which contains the contact form.
- `[_post_author_email]` - This tag will be replaced by the author email of the post which contains the contact form.

So `[_post_url]` should do the trick ;)